# add 3 seconds to handler

Tags: android, timer, handler

I want to create countdown timer that start from 5 secs and by pressing a button, the current time increase by 3 secs.
I used a handler to handle the countdown timer, I know we can`t use CountdownTimer.
Here is my code:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 int delay = 1000;
r = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        int timeOut = finalTime - 1;
                        String printedTime = Integer.toString(timeOut);
                        timer.setText(printedTime);
                        handler.postDelayed(this,delay);
                };
```

I updated, Here is the correct code in simple way:

```
timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    addSecs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addSecs);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            currentTime = timer.getText().toString();
            time = Integer.parseInt(currentTime);
            time-=1;
            updateTime = Integer.toString(time);
            timer.setText(updateTime);
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
        }
    },1000);

    addSecs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentTime = timer.getText().toString();
            time = Integer.parseInt(currentTime);
            time+=3;
            updateTime = Integer.toString(time);
            timer.setText(updateTime);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm assuming `timeOut` and `finalTime` are in seconds? Just increase the `finalTime+=3` on your button `onClick(View v)` event

Comment: @Carpetfizz Yes they are in seconds, and brilliant. I missed that in onClick. Thanx aloooooot...

Answer (score 0):

Use can change below code according to your logic timer

use CountDownTimer

1st param is the starting timer in miliseconds,
2st params is count down interval

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //5 ,4 , 3, 2, 1
        Log.d(TAG,"starting nuclear in " + (millisUntilFinished/1000));
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //finish code
    }

}.start();
```

If you want to use Handler

```
timeOut = 5;
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      /* do what you need to do */
      Log.d(TAG,"starting nuclear in " + timeOut--);
      /* and here comes the "trick" */
      if(timeOut > 0)
          handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
   }
};

private Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```